# Tex csname index off by one inside loop

Tags: macros, loops

I'm trying to write a write a simple implementation of a list of notation (more as a technical exercise than for actual use). I've run into a rather strange issue with numberings. The following is my implementation of the two relevant commands. The `\notation` command creates a custom macro which contains the "notation" and the current page number (this seems to work OK), and the `\listofnotation` command prints all defined notation into a list. The problem is that, calling `\notation{one}` defines the macro `\notation@1` and `\notation{two}` creates `\notation@2` as expected. However, when I call `\listofnotation`, the output is `\notation@1 two 1` and not `\notation@1 one 1\par\notation@2 two 1` as I expect. Changing the starting index of `\loopingindex` to 0 makes it work as expected, but the output is
`\notation@0 one 1\par\notation@1 two 1`. This is quite peculiar.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\notationcount

\newcommand\notation[1]{%
\global\advance\notationcount by1%
\expandafter\protected@edef\csname notation@\the\notationcount%
\endcsname{\protect{#1}\hskip1em\thepage}%
\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\notationcount\endcsname%
}

\newcommand\listofnotation{%
\newcount\loopingindex%
\loopingindex=1%
\expandafter\ifx\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\relax\else
\section*{List}%
\noindent%
\loop\expandafter\ifx%
\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\relax%
\else%
\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname~%
\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\par\noindent%
\advance\loopingindex by1%
\repeat%
\fi%

}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\notation{one}
\notation{two}

\listofnotation

\end{document}
```

I notice that the implementation is similar to that in the second example of https://www.tug.org/tug2012/booklet/hendrickson/AmyTugProc.pdf

*Disclaimer:* I had a quick look for a duplicate, but I wasn't really sure what to search for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong `%` at the end of a line:

```
\newcommand\notation[1]{%
\global\advance\notationcount by1%
\expandafter\protected@edef\csname notation@\the\notationcount%
\endcsname{\protect{#1}\hskip1em\thepage}%
\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\notationcount\endcsname%
}
```

The `%` in excess is at the end of line 2; when TeX is doing the assignment to `\notationcount`, it expands tokens until something which cannot be interpreted as a digit is found. In your case it expands `\expandafter` that triggers `\csname` into making a token out of those it finds up to `\endcsname`, *expanding* as it goes, so `\the\notationcount` is expanded ***before*** the assignment to it has been performed, so to the previous value!

I use to call this the *missing required space syndrome*. `;-)` Solution:

```
\newcommand\notation[1]{%
\global\advance\notationcount by1
\expandafter\protected@edef\csname notation@\the\notationcount%
\endcsname{\protect{#1}\hskip1em\thepage}%
\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\notationcount\endcsname%
}
```

A space after a numeric constant is ignored.

There are other glitches in your code; for instance,

```
\newcount\loopingindex
```

should go outside the definition of `\listofnotation`; not really important here, but better programming style nonetheless.

The `\protect` token is completely misplaced and its effect can be from doing nothing to making a disaster. You can just `\protect` just *one* token, not a braced list of them.

The main defect, though, is that using `\thepage` is not safe unless you're in the output routine or a page has just been started after `\newpage`, `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`. How to solve this depends on how you intend to use your macros; passing through the `.aux` file is generally the safest way.

Here's a fixed version of your macros, with `%` in the appropriate places. I haven't tried to do the two pass approach which should be needed, though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\notationcount

\newcommand\notation[1]{%
  \global\advance\notationcount by 1
  \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname notation@\the\notationcount\endcsname{%
    #1\hskip1em \thepage
  }%
  \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\notationcount\endcsname}%
}

\newcount\loopingindex % NOT inside the definition!

\newcommand\listofnotation{%
  \loopingindex=1
  \expandafter\ifx\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\relax
  \else
    \section*{List}
    \noindent
    \loop\expandafter\ifx\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\relax
    \else
      \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname}~%
      \csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\par\noindent
    \advance\loopingindex by 1
    \repeat
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\notation{one}
\notation{two}

\listofnotation

\end{document}
```

[image]

An implementation that uses the `.aux` file, so giving precise page numbers under any circumstance (provided the list has not been modified in the previous run):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcount\notationcount

\newcommand\notation[1]{%
  \global\advance\notationcount by 1
  \protected@write{\@auxout}{}{%
    \string\stored@notation{\the\notationcount}{#1}{\thepage}%
  }%
  \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\notationcount\endcsname}%
}
\newcommand{\stored@notation}[3]{%
  \global\@namedef{notation@#1}{#2\quad#3}%
}

\newcount\loopingindex % NOT inside the definition!

\newcommand\listofnotation{%
  \loopingindex=1
  \expandafter\ifx\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\relax
    \typeout{No notation defined; rerun LaTeX}%
  \else
    \section*{List}
    \noindent
    \loop\expandafter\ifx\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\relax
    \else
      \texttt{\expandafter\string\csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname}~%
      \csname notation@\the\loopingindex\endcsname\par\noindent
    \advance\loopingindex by 1
    \repeat
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\notation{one}
\newpage
\notation{two}
\newpage
\notation{thr\'ee}

\listofnotation

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it. I did spend quite a lot of time trying to figure out how to correctly expand the `\thepage` so that the correct page number is output in the list. I eventually settled on using `\edef`, which then caused problems when fragile commands were used as the argument for the `\notation` macro. Thus the switch to `\protected@edef`. The purpose of these macros was to construct a list of notation from my thesis and print the list at the end. (Without appealing to glossary/indexing packages.)

Comment: @SamM I added an implementation using the `.aux` file in order to have correct page number references.

Comment: in the definition of `notation@#1' do we not need `#2\quad\thepage` (or similar), it looks like this prints the value of `\notationcount`?

Comment: @SamM Yes, you're right, sorry: there should be three parameters. I'll fix it in a moment.